# How to get latest billing invoice details with an order ID

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a SoftLayer order ID which you see when you go to Account -> Sales -> Orders in the SoftLayer control panel. And I have the SoftLayer API credential for the account. Is there a way to get the latest billing or invoice information for this order? What SoftLayer API and what object mask do I need?

This is what I am using currently:

```
$slClient = SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Billing_Order', $baseInfoJSON->slOrderId, $baseInfoJSON->slApiUser, $baseInfoJSON->slApiKey);
$mask = 'mask[description,hostName,domainName,billingItem.cancellationDate,billingItem.createDate,billingItem.currentHourlyCharge,billingItem.cycleStartDate,billingItem.description,billingItem.hourlyRecurringFee,billingItem.hoursUsed,billingItem.laborFee,billingItem.laborFeeTaxRate,billingItem.modifyDate,billingItem.nextBillDate,billingItem.oneTimeFee,billingItem.oneTimeFeeTaxRate,billingItem.recurringFee,billingItem.recurringFeeTaxRate,billingItem.setupFee,billingItem.setupFeeTaxRate,billingItem.nextInvoiceTotalOneTimeAmount,billingItem.nextInvoiceTotalOneTimeTaxAmount,billingItem.nextInvoiceTotalRecurringAmount,billingItem.nextInvoiceTotalRecurringTaxAmount,billingItem.invoiceItem,billingItem.invoiceItem.description,billingItem.invoiceItem.createDate,billingItem.invoiceItem.hourlyRecurringFee,billingItem.invoiceItem.invoiceId,billingItem.invoiceItem.laborAfterTaxAmount,billingItem.invoiceItem.laborFee,billingItem.invoiceItem.oneTimeAfterTaxAmount,billingItem.invoiceItem.oneTimeFee,billingItem.invoiceItem.recurringAfterTaxAmount,billingItem.invoiceItem.recurringFee,billingItem.invoiceItem.setupAfterTaxAmount,billingItem.invoiceItem.setupFee,billingItem.invoiceItem.invoice,billingItem.invoiceItem.invoice.companyName,billingItem.invoiceItem.invoice.id,billingItem.invoiceItem.invoice.accountId,billingItem.invoiceItem.invoice.typeCode,billingItem.invoiceItem.invoice.statusCode,billingItem.invoiceItem.invoice.amount,billingItem.invoiceItem.invoice.createDate,billingItem.invoiceItem.invoice.closedDate,billingItem.invoiceItem.invoice.endingBalance,billingItem.invoiceItem.invoice.invoiceTotalAmount,billingItem.invoiceItem.invoice.invoiceTotalOneTimeAmount,billingItem.invoiceItem.invoice.invoiceTotalPreTaxAmount,billingItem.invoiceItem.invoice.invoiceTotalRecurringAmount]';
$slClient->setObjectMask($mask);
$result = $slClient->getItems();
```

And I can see I have a latest recurring invoice in this account which was generated on May 1st and it includes 2 hourly Virtual Servers that I placed order back in March and April along with some other storage devices.

When I make same API call for another order(order ID 7317809), it picks up the information from the latest invoice(the recurring invoice ID 8363665).

But when I make above API call for one of the orders(order ID 7787659), it picks up the information from earlier invoice (invoice ID 8206439).

Why are some order IDs NOT getting picked up from latest invoice which includes the order item?  If the "NEW" invoice is the latest invoice which contains my order item, then the API should get the invoice information for my item from this "NEW" invoice.  If the "RECURRING" invoice is the latest invoice which contains my order item, then the API should get the invoice information for my item from this "RECURRING" invoice.

Which API and what object mask will give me such billing information that I am looking for given an order ID?

I am including a screen capture of part of this "RECURRING" invoice showing both of these virtual servers.

[image: My Invoice]

Answer (score 0):

This request may help you:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Order/getAllObjects?objectMask=mask[id,account[ latestRecurringInvoice[id,statusCode]],createDate, orderApprovalDate, orderTotalAmount,status, initialInvoice[id, invoiceTotalAmount, statusCode],orderTopLevelItems[description] ]

Method: GET
```

**Where:**

The `"latestRecurringInvoice"` is the property that you are looking for.

Using `objectFilters`, the request could be:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Order/getAllObjects?objectMask=mask[id,account[ latestRecurringInvoice[id,statusCode]],createDate, orderApprovalDate, orderTotalAmount,status, initialInvoice[id, invoiceTotalAmount, statusCode],orderTopLevelItems[description] ]&objectFilter={   "id": {     "operation": 7787659} }

Method: GET
```

**Where:**

`7787659` is the order_id.

Comment: Thank you.  The "lastRecurringInvoice" was helpful and I think I need to use getObject() instead getAllObjects().  Also using some other objectMask with initialInvoice, account.invoices, and account.latestRecurringInvoice, and matching up the billingItem.id, I think I can use those data to figure out what I need.